# CSS3 bi-directional Flipper

Tags: css, right-to-left

I'm looking for a CSS converter LTR to RTL that supports the new CSS3 transforms

for example:

```
pre {
    width: 33em;
    border: solid red;

    -webkit-transform: translate(100px) rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 60% 100%;

    -o-transform:translate(100px) rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform-origin:60% 100%;

    transform: translate(100px) rotate(20deg);
    transform-origin: 60% 100%;
}
```

this example represents LTR CSS, I want a tool to give me the RTL version of the provided CSS

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood which effect you want to achieve, do you want to animate the transition between LTR and RTL ?

Comment: @Yaser can you clearly define your expected output, unfortunately at the moment its not clear what you currently have, nor what you want

Comment: The example I posted is LTR CSS, I want a tool to give me the RTL version of the provided CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) is what you are looking for, output produced by your example as input:

```
pre {
     width: 33em;
     border: solid red;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-100px) rotate(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 40% 100%;

    -o-transform:translate(-100px) rotate(-20deg); 
    -o-transform-origin:40% 100%;

    transform: translate(-100px) rotate(-20deg);
    transform-origin: 40% 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle: [LTR Version](http://jsfiddle.net/M2Fp3/show)

jsfiddle: [RTL Version](http://jsfiddle.net/M2Fp3/1/show)

Direct links:

Github: https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss

NPM: https://www.npmjs.org/package/rtlcss